# Using a Tamron 70-300mm for Nikon on my Canon EOS 200D

Tags: canon, nikon, lens-adapter, tamron

Maybe a dumb question for Pros like you but I really have no idea: I got a Tamron 70-300mm F4-5.6 A005 **FOR NIKON** - but I have a **Canon 200D** (it was gift, because the person doesn't need it anymore). Is there any possibility to use it on my camera with an adapter or something else?
I can't find any information about this so I hope somebody can help me here. I am an absolute newbie in this theme, so please explain it with simple words :-D
Thank you in advance,
Elena

Answer (score 1):

There are adapters that convert Nikon lenses to Canon. Prices vary greatly, and the result is never satisfactory. You will lose most of the automatic features like focus, aperture control, and image stabilisation. You'll find more information [here.](https://expertphotography.com/nikon-to-canon-lens-adapter/) That article also talks about one particular adapter model. You'll find more on [Amazon.](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=nikon%20to%20canon%20adapter&ref=nb_sb_noss_2)

I suspect you would be better off selling the lens on fleeBay, and using the money to buy an equivalent Nikon lens. You'll lose a bit of cash, but it's worth it in the long run.